# JS redirection when using sweet alert

Tags: javascript

I'm using sweet alert for my website but would like to know how I could execute a php script which is in another page once the user has confirmed his action.

Here is a sample of the code :

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><p onclick="go()">Approve/Refuse</p></a>
```

**JS**

```
function go() {
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Validate user',
    cancelButtonText: 'Refuse request',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger m-l-10',
    buttonsStyling: false
  }).then(function() {
    swal(
      'User validated!',
      'The user has been notified.',
      'success',
    )
  }, function(dismiss) {
    // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
    // 'close', and 'timer'
    if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
      swal(
        'User refused',
        'The user has been notified.',
        'error'
      )
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: call to php script from ajax call

Comment: What do you mean: PHP script which is in another page? Isn't your PHP script on the backend and you wanna make ajax call to it?